# Prove $J=\langle Y^{3}-X,Z^{5}-Y^{4}\rangle$ prime or $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/J$ integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to prove one of the following (equivalent) statements: that the ideal $J=\langle Y^{3}-X,Z^{5}-Y^{4}\rangle$ is prime or that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/J$ is an  integral domain.

My teacher told me that proving that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/J$ is an integral domain is easier, but I don't know where to start.

I thought maybe I could find an isomorphism to a well known integral domain, but the fact that it is generated by two polynomials and that there is no easy parametrization is making this difficult to me.

I tried an isomorphism to $\mathbb C [X, X^{1/3}, X^{4/15}]$, but he asked me what meaning $X^{1/3}$ and $X^{4/15}$ had (we never used polynomial rings with fractional powers in this subject) and I didn't know what to answer.

So maybe there is another (easier) way that I didn't thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the quotient we have $X=Y^3$, so $X$ is redundant, i.e. your ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[Y,Z]/(Z^5-Y^4).$ Since $\mathbb{C}[Y,Z]$ is a UFD, you need to show $Z^5-Y^4$ is irreducible. This is true because $4$ and $5$ are coprime (see here: [Necessary and sufficient condition for $x^n - y^m$ to be irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489289/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-xn-ym-to-be-irreducible-in-bbb-c/2480496#2480496)).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use $\Bbb C[X,X^{1/3},X^{4/15}]$, use $\Bbb C[T^{15},T^5,T^4]$
(a subring of $\Bbb C[T]$). She can't complain about that. Map $X$ to
$T^{15}$, $Y$ to $T^5$ and $Z$ to $T^4$. Then all you have to do
is to show the kernel is generated by $X-Y^3$ and $Y^4-Z^5$.