# Is $x^n - y^m$ irreducible ($n, m$ strictly positive integers with $n \ne m$)?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves, prime-factorization, polynomial-rings

For $n$ and $m$ strictly positive integers with $n \ne m$, I guess that $x^m - y^n$ is  irreducible in any field, but I am not sure. In particular, I have no idea how this could be proved. My question is thus:

1. Is $x^m - y^m$ irreducible ? In any field, or only in fields with some restriction?
2. If yes, how to prove it ? If no, is there a concrete counterexample?

Comment: $x^2-y^4=(x-y^2)(x+y^2)$. I think you need $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necessary and sufficient condition for $x^n - y^m$ to be irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489289/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-xn-ym-to-be-irreducible-in-bbb-c). Also [$X^n-Y^m$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$ iff $\gcd(n,m)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652392/xn-ym-is-irreducible-in-bbbcx-y-iff-gcdn-m-1) (and linked questions)

Comment: Title: "irreductible" should be "irreducible".